# Scroll bar not appearing with modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a issue that my scroll bar does not appear when more elements are added to the page. I also have a modal that overlays the entire page when you click on an item.

However, the modal does not appear if I change the `position: fixed` to something else in the CSS.

So my question is, how do I make it so that the scroll bar appears and the modal still overlays correctly?

Here are some images:

[Elements with no scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILxAb.png)

[Modal overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLssd.png)

[Elements with scroll bar, but no modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn2Qv.png)

**App.css:**

```
.page-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
}

.modify-modal-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.modify-modal-container-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**Index.css:**

```
body, html, #root, .App {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: white;
}
```

**As you can see with the above pictures, I can get the scroll bar to appear. But when trying to click on an item to open the modal, it does not appear / open.**

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can we have some HTML to have more context and investigate further? Try creating an snippet as this explains https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0):

Changing `.page-container{}` position to **absolute** and changing `.modify-modal-container{}` **position** to fixed.

This fixed my issue!